# How can I connect to Denodo using Python Pandas and SQLAlchemy?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to connect to Denodo using Python SQLAlchemy, and create a DataFrame from a table. My environment is Cloudera Data Science Workbench. Can I use psycopg2 and the PostgreSQL connection string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work as Denodo dabbled with PostgreSQL schemas and is thus not compatible with it (or any other dialect). I use `engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://DenodoODBC")`. DenodoODBC settings are taken from my ODBC Data Sources.

EDIT
In April, Denodo added a [python connection guide](https://community.denodo.com/kb/view/document/How%20to%20connect%20to%20Denodo%20from%20Python%20-%20a%20starter%20for%20Data%20Scientists?tag=ODBC%20driver):

Comment: Thanks! did you use it from your local machine? Had difficulties installing any drivers for CDSW. Anyway no worries.

Comment: Alternatively, you can try `pyodbc.connect(DSN="your_dsn")` (works) or experiment e.g. as described here [Accessing External SQL Databases](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/data-science-workbench/1-6-x/topics/cdsw_import_data.html). On Linux, you can use unixODBC and add a Denodo entry to your odbc.ini (see [Install the ODBC driver on Linux - Denodo](https://community.denodo.com/docs/html/browse/6.0/vdp/developer/access_through_odbc/configuration_of_the_odbc_driver_in_linux_and_other_unix/install_the_odbc_driver_on_linux). We made it work on an Amazon EC2 instance. Good luck...